# 4 Doors and a Half Value prize

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, monty-hall

You're on a game show, playing for 1 million dollars! You've made it to the final round, there are 4 doors, you pick a random door (obviously, there's a 1/4 chance for all of them, let's say you picked #3.) The host reveals door #1, it's empty. You now have the choice to stick with your door, switch to another door, or take 5 hundred thousand dollars! Which should you take?

Comment: Seriously, if I had the choice between just taking half a million or I had a 1 out of 3 chance of getting nothing... it should be clear to anyone except the greedy.

Comment: You're not saying what the *strategy* of the host is, i.e. *why* he chooses door #1. Therefore the answer is as undefined as with all those mis-told versions of the Monty Hall puzzle. Please elaborate.

Comment: I agree with general crispy: choose a door: significant chance of being sad: take 1/2 million: zero chance of being sad.  Easy choice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Note**: I assume the host knew door #1 would be empty. This is analogous to the original Monty Hall problem. If the host randomly opens a door, the door-opening is moot and can be left out completely.

Let's first look at the situation without the 500K consolation prize:

Let's say I do NOT switch doors, then I have a 25% chance to win 1 million.

Let's say that I *do* switch:

1. I pick the right door immediately (25% chance). Switching wins me nothing.
2. I pick the wring door first (75% chance). After the elimination of a wrong door, I switch with a 50% chance to win 1 million.

I have in total $\frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{8}$ chance of winning the 1 million.

So switching is, like in the original Monty Hall problem, certainly beneficial, raising my chance of winning from $\frac{1}{4}$ to $\frac{3}{8}$.

However, my expected win is $\frac{3}{8} \times \text{1 million}$. That is less then the 500K.

Basically, I have a choice to gamble a sum of money with the chance of doubling it, but I have only $\tfrac{3}{8}$ chance of doubling it. Going by the math, I should stick with the money I have, which means
**I should choose to keep the 500k**.

This problem introduces something that is not in the original problem, and that is *utility*. That is the phenomenon that what I can win changes my life much more than the money I lose. It is the reason people play in lotteries with a negative expected return (winning some millions changes your life. Paying some dollars every month makes no change. So even if I never win, the possible win is much more important than the almost certain loss).

Now, in the case of "investing" 500k at bad odds to double it, this doesn't seem to play (both 500k and 1 million are "a lot of money!), but let's say I have a loan shark on my case who will kill me if I do not pay him back 1 million tomorrow. Now, the 500k will do me no good at all.
In this situation, I will certainly select another door, giving me a 3/8 chance of surviving tomorrow. (Versus taking the 500k which will see me dead, or not switching and sticking with my original door, which gives me 25% chance of survival).

Comment: Awesome job! Just the answer I was looking for!

Comment: +many for mentioning the utility of money - which so many of these problems ignore!

Comment: @JuliaHayward honestly, how important is that? I mean, it's an interesting thought, but do we really need to add "but what if there is a crazed gunman demanding one million dollars" to every question? It's safe to assume each question wants a strategy maximizes expected dollar outcome, unless a utility breakdown is explicitly stated.

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop: The guntoting madman is only relevant when there is a small difference in order of size between the prizes. Utility only comes into play when it influences the strategy. It is an essential difference between the original MH problem (which is always, in any strategy, an all-or-nothing game) and this variation (where I may have the opportunity to select my strategy based on utility). A more common occurrence of utility is indeed in standard lotteries, where the expected result is negative, and yet people play (small loss = no change, but big win = big change).

Comment: I'm moreso commenting on the arbitrary inclusion of an extra factor. You could have just as easily included a change in strategy for when the madman will steal money from you if you swap, or if you choose 3, his unlucky number. Why include one but not the other? I suppose you can include what's interesting to you, but I was responding to the sentiment that it's something people should be rewarded for doing.

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop: Utility is not an arbitrary factor. Utility is a consistent factor in _any_ strategy when the game is not all-or-nothing. Ignoring it when it should be included leads to incorrect analysis. If you discard utility, almost every single lottery in the world can only be explained with "people are stupid", whereas utility actually provides a rationale for participating. It is certainly not _arbitrary_, but it _is_ very often ignored or forgotten.

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop The mad gunman is a very extreme and arbitrary element of utility, presumably added to make the point. In a real world game show, though, it's perfectly conceivable that someone may be influenced by the utility of *enough money to achieve a major life goal* to value keeping that amount over risking it all for a higher amount.

Comment: @JuliaHayward But this is puzzling, not real life. Even if utility is applicable to the strategy, there's no need to make a special case for ever possible utility function that would affect the outcome. The arbitrariness isn't just that utility is included, it's that there are infinite possible utility functions, and you chose one or two. What if money is suddenly of negative utility? What if any amount of money is acceptable, but debt is deadly to you? Again, I'm mostly just saying that it's not as crucial to the puzzle as you two make it sound.

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop: What if I would have the choice between keeping 5 dollar vs. winning 50 million, at similar comparative odds as this question (meaning my expected return is $3.75), would inclusion of utility still be arbitrary?

Comment: @oerkelens In a *puzzle* where utility analysis is not explicitly desired, yes. It's not wrong to include it, but it's just an interesting side note rather than an important part of the answer.

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop: so a puzzle with the parameters as I set them in my earlier remark would only be answerable by "don't play, you have 5 dollars and your expected result is 3.75 dollars"? I think you miss out on one of the more _human_ aspects of game theory (and thus on some of the more interesting solutions to these kind of puzzles, because the puzzle with these parameters is a real-life one, and the answer is, in real life **not** _don't play_)

Comment: I suppose I really must emphasize that *this is not about humanity or game theory as a whole*. Puzzles tend to have absurd premises (like aliens who will kill people who don't know their hat color) to justify a very specific and limited puzzle premise. So this is my final thought on the matter: Include comments about utility whenever you want, because they're often interesting. However, realize that that's not actually relevant to the question, and you shouldn't expect their presence in answers unless explicitly stated.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the money , because its higher than the probability of winning the chance which is 1/3rd (Edit: its 3/8 as explained in the other answer), but that is assuming the host knows which door it is in.

Comment: The chance of winning is 1/4th. But yes, keep the money!

Comment: @Mathias711 It's 1/3 because an empty room has been eliminated

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/the-monty-hall-problem

Comment: If there were 1000 doors, and 998 would be eliminated by the presentator (and he knows which doors do not have the money), would you say that the chance that my initial guess has 50% chance?

Comment: @Mathias711 You are making an assumption that the host knew door #1 was empty. That has not been stated here.

Comment: The probability of winning with switching is not 1/4. It is 3/8.

Comment: @JoelRondeau: true, that assumption is made. The opposite is not stated either, both are possible, and the assumption is based on the original Monty Hall problem.

Comment: @oerkelens Agreed. Both are possible and regardless of which, you take the money.

Answer (score 0):

Take the $500,000.

I assume that opening a door for an empty room means you get nothing.

You picked on, and one was eliminated. So, there is now a $1/3$ probability of picking the correct door from the remaining 3. \$500,000 $> 1/3*1000000$.

Comment: This is not true. The chance is 1/4 * 1000000. See the Monty Hall problem. The answer is still right, but the calculation isn't

Comment: Yes, @Mathias711: see the Monty Hall problem. The chance is 3/8 to win the million, not 1/4 (if you switch, of course)