# Monty's At Random Hall

Tags: logical-deduction

There are three doors. Behind one of them is a car. You want that car. Behind the other two doors are goats.

You pick a door, but it is not opened.

The host, Monty, opens one other door at random, and he asks you if you want to keep your selection, or switch to the third door, which has not been opened.

Monty has no idea what is behind each door, and nor do you. Is it better for you to switch your selection, or not?

Comment: If Monty has no idea what is behind each door, then could the door he opens randomly have a car behind it (thus making the whole problem trivial)?

Comment: @randal'thor Since Monty opens a door at random, yes, there could be a car behind it, but only if your initial selection was not the car.

Comment: In the version of this I've heard before, he does know what is behind the doors, and the opened one is a goat.

Comment: @HerbWolfe Yes, that's [the classical Monty Hall problem](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/the-monty-hall-problem?rq=1).

Comment: @Downvoters, any reason?

Comment: Yeah, not sure why this got downvotes.

Comment: @Ben: Because it's a simple calculation. Not much of a puzzle.

Comment: @Deusovi Well, personally, I find it interesting. In my opinion, if you're downvoting it because it's too easy, just answer it. If you enjoyed answering it, consider upvoting it instead.

Comment: @TheBitByte: ...But I *did* answer it. You made six comments on my answer!

Comment: @Deusovi I was not talking specifically about you, but rather about downvoters in general.

Comment: @Deusovi No more so than the original Monty Hall, which is one of the most famous probability riddles going.

Comment: i saw this in the movie 21 Blackjack

Comment: @BenAaronson, the original Monty Hall gives a result, which is surprising and counterintuitive for many people, making it an interesting problem. In this variation there is nothing surprising, so this variation is simple calculation indeed. Also the story does not make sense: if Monty opens the door with the car behind it (which might happen), he basically ruins the game.

Comment: There is missing information: Will Monty _always_ open a random other door, or is this dependent on what you found? If he only opens a random door if your door had a car / had a goat then you should stay / switch after he opens the door.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference between sticking and switching.

> [image] (Doors 2 and 3 look the same.)

Comment: Mine is based on an incorrect assumption about the question, and is not correct.

Comment: @TheBitByte "Can't happen" is for Monty opening the same door as you. "Doesn't matter" is for Monty opening the door with the car.

Answer (score 1):

> In the original version of the puzzle, you have a 1 in 3 chance of getting the car if you don't switch, but now, in this version, you have a 1 in 2 chance of getting the car if you do switch, and the same chance if you don't, so switching or not makes no difference.

The reasoning is based on:

> In the original Monty Hall, the contestant has twice as many (2/3) chances of getting the car if he switches, because Monty does not reveal a car.
>  In this version, there is a 1/3 chance of Monty revealing a car. 2/3 of the time the contestant doesn't pick the car, and 1/2 of those times, Monty will. (2/3) * (1/2) = 1/3.
>  The remaining 1/3 of the time, neither the contestant, nor Monty have picked the car.
>  1/2 of the time that Monty does not reveal the car, the contestant will pick it by switching, so, NO, it is not better to switch.
>  The times that Monty picks the car, switching is irrelevant, as there is no chance of picking the car.
>  Therefore, your chances of winning are the same whether you switch or stay.

Comment: There's two doors left, the one you picked and the one you can switch to. If the one you can switch to has a 1/2 chance of being correct, then shouldn't the one you picked have 1/2 as well? Since the probabilities have to sum to 1

Comment: Initially, no, as there are 3 doors to start.

Comment: Yeah, I mean after the door is opened.

Answer (score 1):

> If Monty opens the door with a car, you would switch your selection to the door Monty opened at random. If he opened a door with a goat, then there is a goat and a car left, with 50/50 probability of either being your original selection. So it is better to switch your selection if he shows you the car, otherwise it makes no difference.