# The Monty Hall loot box

Tags: mathematics, strategy, probability, monty-hall

Everyone sufficiently competent in probability knows that in [The Monty Hall problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/the-monty-hall-problem) as most commonly presented, switching doors wins you the car $\frac23$ of the time. I have come up with this variation:

- There is a pool of cars and goats, initially containing one car and two goats. You always know the pool's exact contents.
- The game is played in an infinite sequence of rounds. Each round begins by sampling three objects *uniformly at random without replacement* from the pool to place behind the doors, again uniformly at random; if the sample does not contain at least two goats the pool is resampled. (Thus there might be three goats and no car, but never one goat and two cars.)
- The standard Monty Hall game is then played: you pick a door, another door is opened revealing a goat, you decide whether to stay or switch.
- *After you win a car or goat one of the opposite object is added to the pool – a car if you won a goat and a goat if you won a car.* The objects behind the doors are returned to the pool and the next round begins. This is similar to a "pity timer" mechanism found in certain [loot boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy#Video_game_players), hence this question's title.

If you play optimally every round:

- What is the limiting proportion of your **wins** that are cars?
- What is the limiting proportion of cars **in the pool**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let w and p ("win" and "pool") the two limiting proportions. Because of the pity timer we have

> $p + w = 1$.

If three goats are drawn we are guaranteed to lose. Otherwise our chances are 2:1 in favour of winning.

The odds for three goats g3 vs two goats one car g2 are (in the limit replacement or not is irrelevant)

> $g3 : g2 = w^3 : 3w^2p = w : 3p$.

Therefore

> $p:w = (g3 + \frac {g2} 3):\frac {2\ g2} 3 = (w+p):2p$

or

> $p = w = \frac 1 2$.